# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on basic button disable

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I made a very basic form. During submission the button is disabled and once the work is done it should be enabled.

However this doesn't work, instead I get the infamous `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

I read Max Koretskyi articles about CD and this exception but can't understand why this happens in this case? It is a simple reaction to an event. Could someone explain in detail what exactly causes this and how could I fix it without `setTimeout` or `Promise`?

Here is the sample code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-err?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fork your Stack-Blitz and make the error disappear by triggering `detectChanges()` on your `finalize`.

[Stack-Blitz with detectChanges](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-err-mxrv3k?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I will try to explain why this is happening. The error seems to be trigger on `finalize` because it runs after the `async pipe`, when the `Observable` completed.

In other words angular trigger the detection check (as always does after a `async` operation if your component is not `OnPush`) but after the detection function is finished the values in the properties checked are not the same and that's the reason that you get that error. If you trigger manual the change detection on `finilize` Angular will check for changes again and everything will be OK.

*(Edited on 2020-09-14)*

Another solution is to add a `delay(0)` to your pipeline before `finalize` or `tap` functions. more details here: [Angular-Debugging](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/).

And that's the sample code of our example: [Stack-Blitz with delay](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-err-ja4nqd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

(Edited on 2019-09-16)

Debugged the code for a while and now it is clear what happens.
Event handler `update()` runs on submit, sets `submissionInProgress` to `true`, and sets the `submissionResult$` observable .
Change detection kicks in after the event. It evalutes other bindings if there are (in the order of your template) then the `submissionInProgress` binding, records its value as true. The next binding is the `async pipe` for `submissionInProgress$`. The `async pipe` notices that its input is not null anymore and subscribes to it. However `of(true)` results a sync observable hence during subscription the observable evalutes. OnNext emits, asyn pipe's `_updateLatestValue` method sets its `_latestValue` field, the observable completes and the `finalize` method runs. Finalize method updates `submissionInProgress` field to `false`. Notice that angular already passed the `submissionInProgress` binding and recorded its value as true, but we just updated the field by `finalize`.
CD records that the `asyn pipe` binding has a value true now.
After these the 2nd round of CD kicks in where it checks for no changes.
It evaluates the `submissionInProgress` binding and sees that the value was true but now it false so it throws the exception.
If we add a `delay` or `setTimeout`, subscription will happen but no business logic will run, the code will remain in the `task queue?`. Stack empties, task queue is processed, the modell will be updated with the emitted value and the finalize's side effect `submissionInProgress = false`. After these will kick in the CD and that's fine now.

Useful points for debugging:

- your event handler's enter and exit
- core.js: `view.detectChanges();`, `view.checkNoChanges();`, `function bindingUpdated(lView, bindingIndex, value)`
- binding points in your html like `*ngIf="async..."`
- common.js: `class AsyncPipe {` functions

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you shed some lights here?

1. click event fires, update method is called, observable created, submissionInProgress is set to true.
2. CD kicks in
2.a It updates the ngIF binding. Is this the time when async magic happens and the observable is subscribed? Shouldn't async pipe trigger another CD? Is finalize also an async event? What the heck happens here?
2.b Update dom, [disabled] should be true if async observable didn't run and false if it ran. I 
3. Dev CD runs in check mode.
Why another CD call in finalize fixes it, does it cancel the running one?

Comment: The problem is that the finalize is triggered when the async event completed. At that moment Angular had already started the process to update the dom but at the end of that process it finds out that the data is not the same with the ones that had when the process started.

As @Shiv said, that error will shown only in dev mode, but I would put the detect change on the `finalize` to be sure that my bindings are correct.

Comment: Shouldn't the CD finish before an async computation is started in the browser?
Why another CD call in finalize fixes it, does it cancel the running one?

Comment: No, the cd should not finish before an async computation is started. In the second answer: I haven't read it somewhere, put I guess that it doesn't cancel the last one, it just understand that another detection is ongoing and it doesn't complain. For more: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: I'll read that. I mean the whole observable subscription happened because of the change detection encountered with the "submissionInProgress$ | async" expression. of(true) subscription should be  a sync call. And I guess finalize should be sync too here as if I change the property instead in a tap() it still throws the exception. The dom should be updated after these happened. Looks like it's not the case. I guess it is executed asyncly, but that should cause another CD... I can't get my head around this.
This nasty CD + async pipe is not really explained anywhere.

Comment: After reading https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/ this article I realise why `tap` has the same problem as `finalize`. A better solution to your problem than trigger `detectChanged()` manually is to add a `delay(0)` before your `finalize` or `tap` function inside your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code like this

```
import { Component, VERSION , ViewRef,ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {forkJoin, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {finalize, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  submissionInProgress = false;
  submissionResult$: Observable<boolean>;

  name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);

  testForm = this.fb.group({
    name: this.name
  });

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private dtr: ChangeDetectorRef,){}

  update(){
      console.info('updateMeta');
      this.submissionInProgress = true;
    this.submissionResult$ = of(true)
      .pipe(
    
        finalize(() => {
          console.info('finalize submissionInProgress = false');
          this.submissionInProgress = false;
             if (this.dtr && !(this.dtr as ViewRef).destroyed) {
            this.dtr.detectChanges();

          }
        }),
      );
  }
}
```